Nextjs 14 jest configuration to use jest.setup.js
in my Nextjs 14 project, in the root directory I have
jest.config.js
const nextJest = require("next/jest");

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: "./",
});

const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"],
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);


and
jest.setup.js
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

with this configs,  I should not need to import @testing-library/jest-dom in each test file AFAIK. However, in this test I get typescript error saying;
Property 'toBeInTheDocument' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<HTMLElement>'
index.test.tsx
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import About from "@/app/about/page";

describe("Home", () => {
  it("renders a heading", () => {
    render(<About />);

    const headingElement = screen.getByText(/About/i);

    expect(headingElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});


What am I missing?

Did you follow the official setup?
